# WxWidgets repository content on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I feel this must be a stupid question because nobody seems to have ask a similar question, yet (regarding my extensive web search).

When I clone the WxWidgets repository from GitHub and try to compile it with MinGW according to all the documentations I find in the internet, I always got an error that some zlib source file has not been found and therefore the comopilation failed.

I went to the src directory and looked into the zlib folder and voilà... it is empty...

Now, when I go to https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/src and browse to the zlib folder, it is NOT empty. However, in the above link, the zlib folder is marked with something like "@ 5888671". Similar marks are at the folders expat, jpeg, png and tiff.
All the mentioned folders are empty when I clone the repository.

In order to solve my compiler errors, I went inside all the mentioned folders and downloaded the content as zip file. I copied the contents of the zip into my locally cloned WxWidgets repository and after that, compiling went through without errors.

The questions now are:

1. How can I clone the repository from GitHub with all the additional contents already in my local version?
2. What does this "@ ...." mark in GitHub mean?
3. Why did I not find a hint of documentation that there is something to take care of with the contents of these special marked folders? IS there some documentation that I just missed?

Thanks in advance,
Maik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to download the submodules with `git submodule update --init`. This will fetch other repository contents linked to this repository in the specified version.

The @ notation in github shows such submodules (after the @ is the short commit hash of the submodule to use).

I think the authors did not mention it because it is a common git feature. You can read more about it here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules

Edit: it is actually mentioned in the repository: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/README-GIT.md

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](http://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/code-repository/), the proper command is:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
```

Comment: Thanks Igor! I was only searching the documentation in the cloned repository (which, as LittleFox proved was not thoroughly enough) and asked google. The Google search did not bring this page up (at least not according to my key words).

Comment: @Kiamur, there is no point to put it in the cloned documentation as you already cloned it. But you should first check the official documentation on the website and then populate the tree. Granted, this age has kind of weird location, but it is explicitly put there for people who will work on the library itself. Application developers usually downloads an official release.